# Why isn't argc same as strlen(argv[i])?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point, argv, argc

Why does my code give segmentation fault when I use strlen(argv[i]) instead of argc?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(argv[i]);i++)
    printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
./a.out
hello
world
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Because you don't take into account `argc`. The `strlen(argv[i])` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You need to be careful when using `strlen()` that doesn't give the count of null terminated byte.

Comment: can ypu tell me how?

Comment: ` for(int i=0;i<strlen(argv[i]);i++)` => ` for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)`

Comment: Would you please tell, what you want to achieve with the above program, then its easy to follow?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I think he just wants to print the command line arguments, see answer below.

Comment: `argc` tells you the number of arguments (including the executable name). `argv` is a list of those arguments. If you want to print all the arguments, you must loop over `argc`. Instead, you're looping over the length of `argv[i]`,, as soon as `i` becomes `>= argc`, you're invoking undefined behavior, manifested in a segfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use argc:

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

For more information, see the answer to this question:
[What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)